# ConnectionTimeout in KSOAP android

Tags: java, android

i am developing an app, in which i have use KSOAP2 library 2.5 for parse wsdl base webservices.now i need to set ConnectionTimeOut in code so i have refer some site and get solution like this...

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                    URL,0);
```

and set catch Exception ...

```
catch (InterruptedIOException  e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Connection Time Out "+e);
        }
```

but it not give me timeout with this code it Execute in common scenario ... so please help me out from this.